# ANTLR reuse subsets of tokens

Tags: antlr, antlr4

In my ANTLR grammar I have a set of operations(OP):

- OP: 'I1', 'I2'....'I9', 'I10' (a set of TOKENS);

whenever I find TOKEN:

- CASE    : valid operations are 'I1','I2','I3' (move1);
- SWITCH  : valid operations are 'I2','I4','I5'    (move2);

the remaining operations are used by other instructions.

Certainly in my Lexer I can't define two tokens as:

```
OP_MOVE1      : 'I1' | 'I2' | 'I3';
OP_MOVE2      : 'I2' | 'I4' | 'I5';
```

because I would get::

**OP_MOVE2 values unreachable. I2 is always overlapped by token OP_MOVE1**

Consequently, imagine that the transactions are not just from I1 to I10 but from I1 to I5000.

One possible solution might be:

LEXER.G4

```
lexer grammar LexerComment;

CASE   : 'CASE' -> pushMode(CASE_MODE); 
SWITCH : 'SWITCH' -> pushMode(CASE_SWITCH); 

WS  : [ \t] -> skip ;   
EOL : [\r\n]+;  

// ------------ Everything INSIDE a CASE ------------ 
mode CASE_MODE;
CASE_MODE_MOVE1 : 'I1' | 'I2' | 'I3'; 

CASE_MODE_WS        : [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN) ;   
CASE_MODE_EOL : EOL -> type(EOL),popMode;

// ------------ Everything INSIDE a SWITCH ------------ 
mode CASE_SWITCH;
CASE_SWITCH_MOVE2: 'I2' | 'I4' | 'I5';

CASE_SWITCH_WS       : [ \t] -> channel(HIDDEN) ;   
CASE_SWITCHT_EOL : EOL -> type(EOL),popMode;
```

PARSER.g4:

```
parser grammar ParserComment;

options {
      tokenVocab = LexerComment;
  }

prog : (line? EOL)+;   
line : instruction; 
 
instruction: CASE CASE_MODE_MOVE1
            |SWITCH CASE_SWITCH_MOVE2;
```

inputFile:

```
CASE I1
CASE I2
CASE I3
SWITCH I2
SWITCH I4
SWITCH I5
```

The grammar seems to work correctly, although I'm not satisfied with the solution as it requires a lot of code, 1 mode for each case, and repetition of tokens in common in the modes.

Also because if I wanted to recognize, in addition to CASE and SWITCH, a line that begins with MOVE1 OR MOVE2 as:

```
 instruction: CASE CASE_MODE_MOVE1
             |SWITCH CASE_SWITCH_MOVE2
             | MOVE1 ;
```

I have not found an optimal solution to solve the problem:

1. I cannot reuse the previous MOVE1 (CASE_MODE_MOVE1);
2. I cannot define a new mode.

Is there a way to correctly handle similar cases?
Given a set of TOKENs I would like a subset that can be used depending on the context.

possibly trying to avoid having to define every single operation as a basic TOKEN:

```
fragment I1: 'I1';
fragment I2: 'I2';
etc
```

**EDIT:**
In my grammar equal TOKEN can have different meanings.

for example with the following grammar the TOKEN I1 has a different meaning.

Parser:

```
parser grammar ParserComment;

options {
      tokenVocab = LexerComment;
  }

prog : (line? EOL)+;   
line : instruction; 
instruction: CONTEXT case_instruction; 

case_instruction
 : I1
 | I2
 | I3
 ;
```

Lexer:

```
 lexer grammar LexerComment;
    
    // I1 IS A CONTEXT
    CONTEXT: I1 | CASE;
    
    CASE   : 'CASE';
    SWITCH : 'SWITCH';
    //OPERATIONS
    I1     : 'I1';
    I2     : 'I2';
    I3     : 'I3';
    I4     : 'I4';
    I5     : 'I5';
    
    WS  : [ \t] -> skip ;   
    EOL : [\r\n]+;
```

despite having the same name, I1 has two completely different meanings (CONTEXT and OP). I would like to recognize these two cases and avoid having a common I1:

```
 prog : (line? EOL)+;   
    line : instruction; 
    instruction: context case_instruction; 
    
    context: I1 | CASE; 
    
    case_instruction
     : I1
     | I2
     | I3
     ;
```

I had tried to manage with modes in the lexer for this reason.

Comment: You should not do `CONTEXT: I1 | CASE;`. That way, there will never be a `I1` or `CASE` token: they will always become a `CONTEXT` token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, you should not let the lexer decide when certain tokens should be created. Let the parser decide when a token is correct in a certain spot.

Something like this:

```
prog
 : instruction* EOF
 ;

instruction
 : CASE case_instruction EOL
 | SWITCH switch_instruction EOL
 | EOL
 ;

case_instruction
 : I1
 | I2
 | I3
 ;

switch_instruction
 : I2
 | I4
 | I5
 ;

CASE   : 'CASE';
SWITCH : 'SWITCH';
I1     : 'I1';
I2     : 'I2';
I3     : 'I3';
I4     : 'I4';
I5     : 'I5';
EOL    : '\r'? '\n' | '\r';
SPACES : [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

Comment: thanks Bart. i was looking for a way to differentiate the common TOKEN. I edited my question :) do you think there is a way? or am I "forced" to use I1 generically.

Comment: My answer is the same: do not do such things in the lexer: let the parser match a certain alternative. When `I1` is matches in parser rule `alt_a` it will have a different meaning than when matches in parser rule `alt_b`

Comment: thanks Bart, i followed your advice